# How to make an if statement in jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        if ( ( item.parent_term_id == "16" ) ) {
           .append( "<a>" + (item.child_term ? item.child_term : + "") + "</a>" )
        }
           .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

This code is belong to JqueryUi Autocomplete widget. I want autocomplete text input to suggest items if their "parent_term_id" is equals to something, else suggest nothing. (It's Wordpress)

But that if statement is not working. Any idea?

Comment: Sometimes it is helpful to put some alerts in to see where the code is breaking. Also if you think that an if block isn't getting called you can try simplifying it or reversing the logic. IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The endless chaining you see in jQuery code is not always the best way to do something.

Here you're better off using a variable:

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    var li = $( "<li></li>" );
    li.data( "item.autocomplete", item );
    if ( ( item.parent_term_id == "16" ) ) {
       li.append( "<a>" + (item.child_term ? item.child_term : + "") + "</a>" );
    }
    li.appendTo( ul );
    return li;
};
```

You could combine some of those, but for the `if`, you have to stop doing the chained function calls, which means using a var.

Answer (score 5):

```
.data( "autocomplete" )
._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  var $li = $( "<li></li>" );

  $li.data( "item.autocomplete", item );

  if ( ( item.parent_term_id == "16" ) ) {
    $li.append( "<a>" + (item.child_term ? item.child_term : + "") + "</a>" );
  }
  return $li.appendTo( ul );
});
```

If you *must* do it on one line (though it does not make sense to do that):

```
.data( "autocomplete" )
._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .filter(function () {
      return item.parent_term_id == "16";
    })
    .append( "<a>" + (item.child_term ? item.child_term : + "") + "</a>" )
    .end()
    .appendTo( ul );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is helpful to put some alerts in to see where the code is breaking. Also if you think that an if block isn't getting called you can try simplifying it or reversing the logic. IE

```
alert("precondition");
if ( ( item.parent_term_id == "16" ) ) {
alert("in if block!");
   li.append( "<a>" + (item.child_term ? item.child_term : + "") + "</a>" );
}
```

simplified

```
alert("precondition");
if ( ( item.parent_term_id) ) {
alert("in if block!");
   li.append( "<a>" + (item.child_term ? item.child_term : + "") + "</a>" );
}
```

reverse logic

```
alert("precondition");
if ( ( item.parent_term_id != "16") ) {
alert("in if block!");
   li.append( "<a>" + (item.child_term ? item.child_term : + "") + "</a>" );
}
```

Comment: It's an another way. Thanks for the tip.